# Using component inheritance and template composing at same time

Tags: angular, templates, inheritance

I read that Angular team said no to such pattern, but still, I want it.

I am trying to make secondary modals.

I have made base component that provides decorations, state of opened and content host.

```
export class BaseModalComponent {
  protected isOpen: boolean = false;

  open() {
    this.isOpen = true;
  }
  close() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="backdrop">
    <div class="modalTarget">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have multiple child components that are actually secondary modals.

```
export class Joe1ModalComponent extends BaseModalComponent {
  public data1!: string;
}
```

```
<base-modal *ngIf="isOpen" (click)="close()">
JOE ONE, {{ data1 }}
</base-modal>
```

it works this way, but it is boring to write `*ngIf="isOpen" (click)="close()"` in each JoeN modal.

If I move this code in BaseModalComponent, it does not work. `isOpen` always shows `false` in rendered template, though variable do change.

Why? What are the caveats of Angular template inheritance and how can I overcome this?